# Error when standardizing variable per group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to standardize a variable within each group. I run into trouble when using the scaled variable in a regression model afterwards when preparing the data using `dplyr`. However this is not the case for `plyr`. Does someone know why?

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars[, c("cyl", "mpg")]     # keep two columns

# standardize using ddply from plyr

df1 <- ddply(df, .(cyl), function(x) {
  x$mpg_scaled = scale(x$mpg)
  x
})

lm(mpg_scaled ~ cyl, data=df1)
```

Results are fine, all works as expected.

```
# standardize using mutate from dplyr

df2 <- df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(
    mpg_scaled = unlist(scale(mpg))
  )

lm(mpg_scaled ~ cyl, data=df2)
```

This throws an error (translated from German):

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg_scaled ~ cyl, data = df2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  Variable lengths are different (found for 'cyl')
```

Also, when accessing the variable `mpg_scaled`, only a few entries are shown.

```
df2$mpg_scaled
            [,1]
 [1,]  0.8648675
 [2,]  0.8648675
 [3,] -0.8567149
 [4,]  1.1400526
 [5,]  1.4062236
 [6,] -1.1302245
 [7,] -0.3124941
 [8,] -0.5019341
 [9,] -0.8567149
[10,] -0.3734655
[11,] -1.3366134
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 26.66364
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 4.509828
```

**What is going on?**

Comment: Try `str(df2)` or `dim(df2$mpg_scaled)` to see what's going on- you have a matrix there. You could fix it using `c(scale(mpg))` or `as.vector(scale(mpg))` for instance. Though for some reason they don't drop attributes while used within `mutate`- yet another awkward dplyr side affect I guess.

Comment: It might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1918) and/or those referenced therein.

Answer (score 0):

You are just unboxing the scaled variable a bit wrong. Check it with:

```
df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
+     mutate(
+         mpg_scaled = scale(mpg)
+     ) %>% str
```

Which prints:

```
Classes 'grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cyl       : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ mpg       : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ mpg_scaled: num [1:11, 1] 0.865 0.865 -0.857 1.14 1.406 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 26.7
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 4.51
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol cyl
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ cyl: num  4 6 8
  ..- attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : symbol cyl
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 3
  ..$ : int  2 7 8 17 18 19 20 25 26 27 ...
  ..$ : int  0 1 3 5 9 10 29
  ..$ : int  4 6 11 12 13 14 15 16 21 22 ...
```

Since mpg_scaled is a matrix, not a list. So this should work:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(
        mpg_scaled = scale(mpg)[,1]
    )
```